# Error running google-app-engine demo

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have installed Google application engine following instructions here: 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing.html

However, running dev_appserver.cmd script causes strange errors:

```
/C/Program Files/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5/bin/dev_appserver.cmd: line 1: @java:
command not found
/C/Program Files/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5/bin/dev_appserver.cmd: line 2: com.goo
gle.appengine.tools.KickStart: command not found
/C/Program Files/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5/bin/dev_appserver.cmd: line 3: com.goo
gle.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain: command not found
```

Same thing happens on WindowsXP 32bit and Windows7 64bit, when running using Windows dos prompt window, and under GNU bash, version 3.1.0(3)-release (i686-pc-msys) shell.

Environment variables:

```
APP_ENGINE_HOME=/C/Program Files/appengine-java-sdk-1.3.5
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16
```

Any suggestions what maybe wrong?

Comment: Do you need some quotes around those paths in a script?  They have spaces in them, after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly doubt that the Bash shell is capable of understanding the `.cmd` script syntax.

If you want to use a Bash shell, you should be able to run `dev_appserver.sh`, which is bundled with the SDK as well as the `.cmd` version.

Comment: The same exact error message shows up when running at Windows prompt.

Comment: You're right, i'm trying to call .cmd script from a shell, and it predictably fails.   And the Windows prompt environment is broken for other reasons. 

thanks!